# Cassandra, spring data, how to add rows

Tags: cassandra, insert, spring-data, nosql

Simple examples in spring data cassandra reference docs show things in a manner SQL mappers do:

```
Insert insert = QueryBuilder.insertInto("person");
insert.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
insert.value("id", "123123123");
insert.value("name", "Alison");
insert.value("age", 39);

cassandraOperations.execute(insert);
```

I'm interested in examples of different kind.

As cassandra (or NONSQL) theology claims, we need model data by queries, that we want execute.

Suppose I have "objects" called "info".

I want query them by category(partitioning key).

Sometime clustering by time,
sometime clustering by tags.

I have 2 TABLES:

```
create table info_by_category_time(
  id uuid,
  title text,
  category text,
  subtitle text,
  authornick text,
  info text,
  link text,
  pic text,
  pic_title text,
  tag1 text,
  tag2 text,
  tag3 text,
  alltags text,
  language text,
  active boolean,
  creation_time timestamp,
  primary key (category, creation_time, tag1, tag2, tag3))
  with CLUSTERING ORDER BY (creation_time DESC, tag1 DESC, tag2 DESC, tag3 DESC)
;

create table info_by_category_tags(
  id uuid,
  title text,
  category text,
  subtitle text,
  authornick text,
  info text,
  link text,
  pic text,
  pic_title text,
  tag1 text,
  tag2 text,
  tag3 text,
  alltags text,
  language text,
  active boolean,
  creation_time timestamp,
  primary key (category, tag1, tag2, tag3, creation_time))
  with CLUSTERING ORDER BY (tag1 DESC, tag2 DESC, tag3 DESC, creation_time DESC)
;
```

Tables are similar, the only difference is - different clustering.

They tell: no problem with data duplication, you need serve your queries - this is more important.

OK!

But how with that schema should I add objects to cassandra, using spring data?

Should I add them to two different tables now in two different operations using 2 different Repository interfaces?

How should I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there is a "user defined type" in cassandra. Which, if used correctly, is the thing that I needed. It allows define a complex type and reuse the definition in different tables. The problem: Spring-data is not yet supporting this UDT. What I plan to do is following: I will define "the reusable" part as BLOB. And so, I can save there any object that I want. And so reuse this object in different tables. Of course , it is a bad workaround, I'm not sure I should continue use spring-data with such a drawback.

Comment: Spring data cassandra 1.5 is supporting UDT now. explained how to use it here : [link ]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862460/user-defined-type-with-spring-data-cassandra/42036202#42036202