# Cassandra: Java class throwing InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException when using cassandra

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra

I'm using spring boot with Cassandra for saving data. But my DB model couldn't work with the annotations of Cassandra.

I'm using Java 11 and Cassandra 3.11.4 for my web service.

class **CasDBNode**

```
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table("node")
public class CasDBNode{

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 0, name = "id", type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String id;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 1, name = "config_id", type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String configId;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private NodeType type;

    @Column
    private List<? extends NodeResponse> responses;

    @Column("parent_node")
    private String parentNode;

    @Column
    private String conditions;

    @Column("previous_sibling")
    private String previousSibling;

    @Column("api_url")
    private String apiUrl;

    @Column
    private List<NodeQuestion> questions;

}
```

class **SimpleNodeQuestion**

```
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@UserDefinedType
public class SimpleNodeQuestion implements NodeQuestion {

    private String title;

    private String output;

    @Column("context_name")
    private String contextName;

    private String condition;

    @Column("option_api")
    private String optionApi;

    @Column("default_options")
    private List<Option> defaultOptions;

}
```

I saw some solutions add @UserDefineType should work, but I still got error

```
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraTemplate' parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Only primitive types are allowed inside Collections for property [questions] of type ['interface java.util.List'] in entity [com.jamesaq12wsx.IBS_Backend.model.db.CasDBNode]
```

## UPDATE

After searching solution, I change the annotation and the error message change

class **CasDBNode**

```
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(value = "node")
public class CasDBNode extends CasDBBaseData implements DBNode{

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 0, name = "id", type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String id;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 1, name = "config_id", type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String configId;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private NodeType type;

    @Column
    private List<? extends NodeResponse> responses;

    @Column("parent_node")
    private String parentNode;

    @Column
    private String conditions;

    @Column("previous_sibling")
    private String previousSibling;

    @Column("api_url")
    private String apiUrl;

    @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.LIST, typeArguments = DataType.Name.UDT, userTypeName = "question")
    private List<DBNodeQuestion> questions;
}
```

class **CasDBNodeQuestion**

```
@UserDefinedType(value = "question")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class CasDBNodeQuestion implements DBNodeQuestion {

    private String title;

    private String output;

    private String contextName;

    private String condition;

    private String optionApi;

    @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.LIST, userTypeName = "option")
    private List<DBOption> defaultOptions;

}
```

the error message change to

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraTemplate' parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: User type [question] not found
```

## update

I changed the `interface` to `class` and it works.

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share the code snippet for CassandraConfig. It is a MappingException. You need to use MappingCassandraConverter for user defined type question.

Comment: Hi @MebinJoe I didn't use CassandraConfig, only set the cassandrad at properties file. I will check out MappingCassandraConverter.

Comment: You could override that and specify a converter. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877213/userdefinedtype-not-found-by-spring-data-cassandra for more info.

Comment: But this problem is different from mine, cause when I change my userDefineType to class instead of an interface, Cassandra driver could find my type.