# Spring Cassandra store a List with custom object's

Tags: java, database, spring, list, cassandra

I like to store a object like:

```
@Table(value = "my_table")
public class MyTableDto {
  @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "uid", type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
  @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.UUID)
  private UUID uid;

  @Column(value = "child_ids")
  private List<ChildIdDto> childIds;
}
```

Then I get the exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Only primitive types are allowed inside Collections for property [childIds] of type ['interface java.util.List'] in entity [de.myapplication.repository.dto.MyTableDto]
```

I do understand the exception, but is there another way to persist custom objects?

**EDIT:**

- When I comment out this attribute, everything works

Comment: what attribute you mean?

Comment: @YCF_L the `childIds`. I just would like to explain, that the exception is not caused by another attribute.

Comment: ok can you try my solution please?

Comment: Annotate childIds by `@Frozen`

Comment: @AshrafulIslam I don't have this Annotation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**!** Never say never, I got the solution.

To give a good example, I will list all according classes.

*ParentClass.java*

```
@Table(value = "my_table") //OPT
public class MyTableDto {
  @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "uid", type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED) 
  @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.UUID)
  private UUID uid;

  @Column(value = "child_ids") //OPT
  private List<ChildDto> childIds;
}
```

*ChildDto.java*

```
@UserDefinedType // THE SOLUTION
public class ChildDto {
  @Column(value = "child") //OPT
  @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TEXT) //OPT
  private String groupId;

  @Column(value = "description") //OPT
  @CassandraType(type = Name.TEXT) //OPT
  private String description;
}
```

The `@UserDefinedType` is the solution.
For more information see [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlRefUDType.html).

**NOTE:** Each annotation with "OPT" is NOT required

Comment: this is nice ;)

Comment: I would add 2 links to describe mapping in spring. In xml: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47511277/3800377 and in java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42036202/3800377