# Having Entity Class as a UDT in Spring Data Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, datastax, spring-data-cassandra

I have a nested POJO as Cassandra entity, where one of the object is a Cassandra entity Class representing a table. I'm trying to model in Spring Data Cassandra and get the following error:

> only primitive types and Collections or Maps of primitive types are allowed

My Entity Structure is as follows

```
//Definition of Single entity
@Table
Class A {
    @Primary Key
    Variable1

    @Column
    Variable2
}

// Definition of nested entity

@Table
Class B {
    @Primary Key
    Variable1

    @Primary Key
    Class A 

    @Column
    Variable2
}
```

How can we achieve above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User Defined Type with spring-data-cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862460/user-defined-type-with-spring-data-cassandra)

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42036202/18627