# Cassandra Table Design: User Defined Types or just holding the id as reference

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I have a user table:

```
@Table
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @PrimaryKey
    private UUID id;

    @Indexed
    private String username;

    ...
}
```

and an Opinion table like this:

```
@Table
public class Opinion {
    ..

    @Indexed
    private User owner;
}
```

Since this referencing of user in opinion does not work automatically, I have found out that you have to declare some extra "user defined types" like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862460/user-defined-type-with-spring-data-cassandra) .. very strange I think.. like many boilerplate code.

This was one of the things which I was used to do for many years with Spring Data, very easily.

Now I have been trying to play with Cassandra DB and I am really not sure how to achieve this.
The question: is this the way of doing this kind of simple referencing stuff? Or should I really just reference the id of user like this?

```
@Table
public class Opinion {
    ..

    @Indexed
    private String owner_id;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said - we just store the reference to the User (in our case it´s the UUID field).

When you need to retrieve the user linked to the Opinion object, you send a second query to the cassandra db.

An other option would be to duplicate the data andfor example store the username directly in the Opinion object. This depends on your application - when this data can change, you would probably need to update all Opinion entries.

Good articles
http://patrickmcfadin.com/2014/02/05/getting-started-with-time-series-data-modeling/
http://planetcassandra.org/blog/escaping-from-disco-era-data-modeling/
http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/07/16/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices-part-1/#.VH-OezHF_6M